# Как управлять сообщениями при выводе с базы данных?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Здравствуйте.

Имеются сообщения в базе данных, которые я подгружаю через php

```
<div class="owl owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"> /* 1 */
    <?php foreach ($rows as $key => $row): ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <p class="name"><?= $row['name'] ?></p>
                <p class="city"><?= $row['city'] ?></p>
                <p class="date"><?= date('d.m.Y', $row['created_at']); ?></p>
                <p class="time"> <?= date('H:i', $row['created_at']) ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. класс, который я буду использовать.

Вопрос таков.

С базы я подгружаю около 20 сообщений.
Как сделать каждое 5 по 8 соообщение в блоке .item, затем 9 по 12 снова в другом .item и тд.?

Спасибо

ps. использую .item как класс owl-carousel.

Comment: в чем логика какая последовательность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получается, что вам нужно распределить все сообщения по `.item`, при этом в каждом `.item` должно быть не больше 4 сообщений, это можно сделать с помощью вложенного цикла, например, так:

```
<div class="owl owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <?php foreach (array_chunk($rows, 4) as $chunk): ?>
        <div class="item">
            <?php foreach ($chunk as $row): ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <p class="name"><?= $row['name'] ?></p>
                        <p class="city"><?= $row['city'] ?></p>
                        <p class="date"><?= date('d.m.Y', $row['created_at']); ?></p>
                        <p class="time"> <?= date('H:i', $row['created_at']) ?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: круто! спасибо, именно то, что мне нужно было)

Comment: @Rustam, отметьте, как ответ, пожалуйста.